# how to specify a property value of a variable in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, org-mode

I use the following code in .emacs file to set default publish behavior. I put the org base directory in difference locations for difference computers:

```
;; define machine specific directories storing my org files
(cond ((system-name-is-home) (setq org-dir "/data/org"))
      ((system-name-is-work) (setq org-dir "~/org")))
```

Thus I'd like to use a variable to specify `:base-directory` to `org-dir` instead of hard-coding it as `"~/org"`. How can I do that?

```
(require 'org-publish)
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(
        ("org-notes"
         :base-directory "~/org"
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "~/tmp/"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html
         :headline-levels 4
         :auto-preamble t

         :auto-sitemap t          ; Generate sitemap.org automagically ...
         :sitemap-filename "sitemap.org" ; ... call it sitemap.org (the default) ...
         :sitemap-title "Sitemap" ; ... with title 'Sitemap'.
         )
        ("org-static"
         :base-directory "~/org"
         :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
         :publishing-directory "~/tmp/"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
         )
        ("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))
        ))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it will be using `` ` `` (backquote) and `,` (comma). From [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html),

> Backquote constructs allow you to quote a list, but selectively evaluate elements of that list. In the simplest case, it is identical to the special form `quote`. (...) The special marker '`,`' inside of the argument to backquote indicates a value that isn't constant. The Emacs Lisp evaluator evaluates the argument of '`,`', and puts the value in the list structure.

So you can write your program as follows:

```
(require 'org-publish)
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      `(                              ; XXX: backquote
        ("org-notes"
         :base-directory ,org-dir     ; XXX: comma
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "~/tmp/"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html
         :headline-levels 4
         :auto-preamble t

         :auto-sitemap t          
         :sitemap-filename "sitemap.org" 
         :sitemap-title "Sitemap"
         )
        ("org-static"
         :base-directory ,org-dir     ; XXX: comma
         :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
         :publishing-directory "~/tmp/"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
         )
        ("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))
        ))
```

Comment: None works: `org-publish-get-base-files: Wrong type argument: stringp, (\, org-dir)` and `org-publish-get-base-files: Wrong type argument: stringp, (\\` org-dir)`

Comment: @RNAer Did you evaluate your `(cond ...)` code that `setq`s `org-dir` before executing the code? I've already checked that the code works when `org-dir` has been set.

Comment: Yes, definitely. I am using `org-dir` in other code lines without any problem.

Comment: Sorry I missed the first modification. Now it works! Thanks a lot!