# emacs major mode definition

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp, major-mode

I am trying to write a very basic emacs major mode to edit assembler source files (for a specific microcontroller). I used https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-test/ModeTutorial as a starting point. It works but I would like to change two things but can't find a solution.

And yes, I am keen to develop a more thorough understanding of eLisp with time, but I also try to quickly hack my way to a working mode definition because I need it now (without really understanding the intricacies - I know, RTFM...).

Anyway, I hope to get an answer to two questions:

1) While syntax highlighting works, I don't get it to be case-insensitive. I tried adding `(setq font-lock-keywords-case-fold-search t)` to the function below, but it does not seem to have the desired effect.

```
(defun xasm-mode ()
   (interactive)
   (kill-all-local-variables)
   (use-local-map xasm-mode-map)         
   (set-syntax-table xasm-mode-syntax-table)
   ;; set up font-lock
   (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults) '(xasm-font-lock-keywords)) 
   (setq font-lock-keywords-case-fold-search t)
   (setq major-mode 'xasm-mode)
   (setq mode-name "XASM")       
   (run-hooks 'xasm-mode-hook))
```

2) The second question for sure demonstrates my ignorance... Basically, in an expression with the structure below, I'd like to substitute the "regexp" literal (which works) by a value that is in a variable (here: x, with x being (correctly) computed by regexp-opt)... But I don't know how to insert the *value* of x here :-(

```
(setq x 'xyz)
(defconst v2
  (list
     '( "regexp" . foo)
))
```

Thanks for your hints.

Comment: Independent of your actual questions, have you looked into `define-generic-mode`? https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Generic-Modes.html

Comment: For your second question, what you're looking for is "backquote", described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11875822/113848), and also [in the elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation with `C-h v font-lock-defaults RET`:

> ...
>   Defaults should be of the form:
>
> (KEYWORDS [KEYWORDS-ONLY [CASE-FOLD [SYNTAX-ALIST ...]]])
>   ...

Which tells you that you can set the "case-fold" behavior right there:

```
(set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults)
     '(xasm-font-lock-keywords nil t))
```

Also, do yourself a favor and use define-derived-mode (and update whichever doc you found that pointed you to `defun+interactive+setqmode-name+...` so it refers to `define-derived-mode` as well).

Answer (score 2):

> While syntax highlighting works, I don't get it to be
>   case-insensitive. I tried adding (setq
>   font-lock-keywords-case-fold-search t) to the function below, but it
>   does not seem to have the desired effect.

Perhaps it's because you use `defun` instead of using the more-modern `define-derived-mode`:

```
(define-derived-mode xasm-mode prog-mode "XASM"
  ;; set up font-lock
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults) '(xasm-font-lock-keywords)) 
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-keywords-case-fold-search) t))
```

If that doesn't work, I guess you'll just have to make it insensitive by hand, `[a-z]` -> `[a-zA-Z]`, etc.

> The second question for sure demonstrates my ignorance... Basically,
>   in an expression with the structure below, I'd like to substitute the
>   "regexp" literal (which works) by a value that is in a variable (here:
>   x, with x being (correctly) computed by regexp-opt)... But I don't
>   know how to insert the value of x here :-(

Use the comma operator as [legoscia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113848/legoscia) pointed out. In your case, it will look like this:

```
(defconst v2
  `(
    ( "regexp" . ,foo)
    ))
```

To evaluate `foo` inside the backtick, we put a comma in front of it, `,foo`.

Comment: I moved to derived-mode, and there case-insensitive matching worked. I started with `defun` because of this (https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeTutorial) example, which was probably not the best idea.